# How to deploy game (accelerometer using unity remote 4,connected with USB)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just want to know if we create a game using Unity remote 4, can we publish/deploy the game instead of testing & playing the game using Unity 5 editor.

If there is a way,could you provide the guidelines.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse you can! Click File -> Build Settings

Put in all your scenes, if you only have one, and you have it open in your editor select 'Add Current'

Then select Build

Select the folder you'd like your build to be in

Wait for your project to be done with building and start it!